# Match Regex CR-00000 pattern

Tags: regex, alteryx

I need a regex expression which would parse my text pattern: CR-000000. There may be a text but somewhere inside would be the pattern, sometimes two -  i need to extract only the part matching the pattern

I have created the following pattern but still doesn't work [CR-]{6}[0-9]

[CR-]{6}[0-9]

From the following example: The change Request has been created for the location below. CR-0001083 Click this link to access the Change Request Change Request ID :  CR-0001086 Property ID:  CK1014   - the output would be  CR-0001083 CR-0001086

Comment: Use `CR-[0-9]{6}`

Comment: I'm not sure why you were using `{6}`, since your pattern has 7 digits.  I'd use `CR-\d{7}`. But also, make sure your search is global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, CR-[0-9]{7} resolves the thing!